# Is it possible to change flex status from bison grammar actions?

Tags: c, bison, flex-lexer, reentrancy

I am building a flex/bison reentrant parser in C, and I am making heavy use of states within the flex lexer, mostly of which are exclusive ones.

But I would appreciate, if possible, to set a lexer state from a bison mid-rule action. 
Is there any possibility to change the lexer state during execution, from bison - i.e. in the middle of a bison rule, through its associated action?

Answer (score 1):

This is possible, but ugly.  In particular the lexer is always in a consistent state when you're back in the parser (as it has returned a token), *but*, it may not be in the state you'd expect as the parser may have done a look-ahead call.

In general feedback between parser and lexer is quite messy.  This is at least in part why gcc's lexer is hand-coded, as the lexer has to return "typedef word" when parsing a C typedef, and "non-typedef variable name" when parsing a C variable declaration, and it's seriously ugly since:

```
typedef int X;
void f(void) {
    X X;
```

is actually legal syntax, using the typedef-name on the left of `X X` and a non-typedef variable name on the right.  (Some of this may have changed since I last was down in the low levels of gcc, which was in the 2.x era. :-) )

If you can handle this some other way, I'd recommend that instead.

Comment: Its not *that* bad -- the parser is at most 1 token ahead of the lexer in basic bison.  The issue with typedefs is independent, as you need to be able to redefine type names in an inner scope, which just means that your grammar has to accept a typedef-name for a declarator in a declaration.  There's no need for any special work in the lexer.

Comment: @ChrisDodd: OK, maybe I oversold it a bit. :-)  I just remember going down this path and backing out, after I realized that this means your lexer becomes dependent on the grammar and whether the parser decided to pull in the next token already.  (Which, yes, you can figure out, but it just seemed like a bad design.)